# Access a dictionary stored in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, nsdictionary

I have a table view controller that a user can select from and it passes a dictionary to a UITabBarController.

How do I get the different views to access the same data stored in the UITabController?

In my UITabBarController

```
@interface MasterTabController : UITabBarController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary * detailDictionary;
@end
```

Is it common practice to keep passing the same data dictionary around? I want to be able to manipulate the data so I can later post it online.

Should I create a singleton? Can I call just the detailDictionary from bView?

[image]

Comment: I suggest reading a bit about MVC structure.  You really don't want a view controller as your data model.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to want to have three different table views, in there different tabs, and set the delegates to their views, and the data source to a custom class in your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create singleton class like this

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      someProperty = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Default Property Value"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

For reference http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/